# Limit accordion content inside React Native Flatlist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to limit the initial number of items rendering inside FlatList. Inside FlatList I  am using Accordion. When I am opening FlatList it is showing many accordions even though I do have one accordion with two headers.I am using react native [collapsible](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible).This is my accordion content:

```
const SECTIONS = [
{
    title: 'First',
    content: 'First World',
},
{
    title: 'Second',
    content: 'Second World',
},
```

];

This is my FlatList

```
 return (
        <FlatList
            style={styles.container}
            data={orders}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={({item}) =>
                <MyOrdersItem {...item} />
            }
            initialNumToRender={1}
            maxToRenderPerBatch={1}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}

        />
    );
```

My OrdersItem is where I am using Accordion.
This is result what I am getting:
[image: click here]

Comment: hi Jasur , according to the docs i found two props for data handling activeSections and sections. could you replicate the demo which is been shown in the repo : https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible

Answer (score 0):

Your FlatList data props should be SECTIONS, not orders.

```
return (
    <FlatList
        style={styles.container}
        data={SECTIONS}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={({item}) =>
            <MyOrdersItem {...item} />
        }
        initialNumToRender={1}
        maxToRenderPerBatch={1}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}

    />
);
```